# How to play music when i click on button in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button

here is the button click method....but the code is giving error

```
" axWindowsMediaPlayer1 doesn't exist in the current context"
```

:( 
plz help me out. I want to play a music when i click on the button.

```
 private void button8_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Visible = false;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = (@"C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\ringtones\Twilight Piano.m4r");
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();


        }

 private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: What is the name you have given to the media player control? Checkout this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: simply use use left hand for the (hammond) keyboard (http://www.google.dk/imgres?imgurl=http://users.belgacom.net/bn479423/download/xk-3img1.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.hammondorgan.co.uk/xk3/index.htm&h=1189&w=3109&sz=244&tbnid=8vMWmVt6-sVE1M:&tbnh=42&tbnw=111&zoom=1&usg=__FcwgVU6QcK8qs-sQ4l4isKb50J0=&docid=ETdu-zkxF2NQnM&sa=X&ei=Ni6FUOGOKoWZ0QXhsoG4BA&ved=0CDYQ9QEwAA&dur=561)

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be you haven't declare `axWindowsMediaPlayer1`. write the following in the beginning of the form:

```
private axWindowsMediaPlayer axWindowsMediaPlayer1 = new axWindowsMediaPlayer();
```

if that's not the problem, check you have all assembly references, and the `using` at the top.

[this site explains step by step how to use axWindowsMediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: i dunno wat assembly reference should be used :(

Comment: do you have an axWindowsMediaPlayer element in your form? Did you change the namespace? The assembly reference is AxInterop.WMPLib.dll

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use a MediaElement you need to create it first. 
You can add it to your xaml like so: 
`<MediaElement Name="axWindowsMediaPlayer1" Visibility="Hidden"  />`

Then you need to declare that you will be controlling the playback

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
```

Then you can load whatever url you want, set the volume, and even have a callback when the music stops. Place the following code in your button.click event handler:

```
Uri noise = new Uri(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + @"\sounds\something.wav"); //Loads from the sounds directory within the project
       axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Source = noise;
       axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Volume = .5;
       axWindowsMediaPlayer1.MediaEnded += new RoutedEventHandler(axWindowsMediaPlayer1_MediaEnded);
       axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Play();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: wat is xaml?? sorry am not very strong in c#... i cant use my code??

Comment: are you building this using WPF or Winforms?

Comment: Ahh, my solution is for WPF. However, you need to add the object to your form. If you did you shouldn't have to declare it. Here is a sample on how to use the axWindowsMediaPlayer: http://grouplab.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/cookbook/index.php/VisualStudio/HowToUseWindowsMediaPlayerToPlayAudioAndVideo